# Can a FullTextSqlQuery in SharePoint use the "This Site" contextual scope?

Tags: search, fulltextsqlquery, contextualscope

I want to limit my full text SQL query to a single site collection and I am calling the SharePoint search.asmx web service directly from Javascript.  Is there some way to limit this using something in the [Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563775)?  This is on SharePoint 2010 Standard.  I realize that Foundation would limit the results on its own, so there must be a way.

Comment: Could you paste your code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like this to your query:

```
AND site = 'http://blah/subsite/anothersite'
```

But in general I'd recommend that you move to KeywordQuery syntax instead of FullTextSqlQuery as the later isn't supported by FAST.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.  This is custom work for a single client that does not use FAST.  I wanted to use a Keyword Query, but the requirements were such that I only query particular fields (not the entire record) so I set up Metadata properties for them.  I know keyword queries can handle this, but I had a few other restrictions which caused the keyword query to never return results.

Comment: Question: Are alternate access mappings handled properly?  If my site can be accessed as http://blah/sites/a or https://blah/sites/a or http://blah.com/sites/a would all work if there are AAMs defined?

Comment: You need to specify the url from the zone which you're crawling. `RebaseUriWithAlternateUri` from [SPAlternateUrlCollectionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spalternateurlcollectionmanager) may help you get that

Comment: I answered my own question.  AAMs are handled.  Thanks!

Comment: I missed your answer to the AAMs before I responded and we have different answers.  My observations indicate that that AAMs _do_ work.  In my case the site name had the servername in one test and a publicly available host header in the second.  Both worked and both returned 0 results if I put a character at the end of the URL (making it a different site).

Comment: Great just wasn't sure